# How to change pop-over view position iPad - obj C

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

i am having little problem here. I have made a popout view activated on toolbard button click. However the view is not in the position i want. See screenshot

1st screen shows what i have and 2nd what i want. 
btw: popview is done problematically. No xib or storyboard involved.
[image]

Some code

```
 -(IBAction)addbutton:(UIToolbar *)sender;
{
        //build our custom popover view
    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]
                                        init];
    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    /*
     * Adding buttons programaticly to popout view
     * button code etc 
     */ 
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(400, 300);

    //create a popover controller
    self.popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc]
                               initWithContentViewController:popoverContent] autorelease];


    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverButton.frame
                                            inView:self.view
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
                                          animated:YES];


    //release the popover content
    [popoverView release];
    [popoverContent release];
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `popoverButton` is probably not a subview of `self.view`, so using its `frame` relative to that will result in an incorrect rectangle. Use `popoverButton.bounds` for the rectangle and `popoverButton` for the `fromView` parameter instead.

Note that the `fromView` parameter does *not* determine in which view the popover will be shown (it'll always be on top of everything), but rather *relative to which* view's coordinate system the rectangle should be interpreted.

Comment: Ok i tried what you have said but i get error message saying 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'"

Comment: Ok solve it :) i was just doing it wrong with the fromView parameter :) it all works now :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

try to change frame `popRect`.

Comment: Tried but it does not work. I have updated question if you could have a look